# Power BI Measure date

Tags: powerbi

I have a table (SalesTable) with list of customers and dates of orders I received from them. I also created a table with Calendarauto function called 'Calendar'.

What I would like to do is to add a measure so to add value 1 to all those orders that were placed before a specific date and and
at the same customers who did not place ANY other order after that date

```
Measure = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('SalesTable'[SalesDate])<MIN(Calendar[Date])||
    SELECTEDVALUE('SalesTabl'[SalesDate])>MAX(Calendar[Date]),
    1,0
)
```

but this shows me in fact only orders that were placed before `MIN(Calendar[Date]` but does not excludes those customers who did not place any other order after that `MIN(Calendar[Date]`

This `MIN(Calendar[Date]` is controlled by slicer

Anyone could help me to modify this?

and here my sample data:

```
Customers        Order no.  Dates of Orders    Expected Results
Customer A       1          01.01.2023         1
Customer A       2          02.01.2023         1
Customer E       3          03.01.2023         1
Customer E       4          04.01.2023         1
Customer E       5          05.01.2023         1
Customer C       6          06.01.2023         0
Customer C       7          07.01.2023         0
Customer C       8          08.01.2023         0
Customer B       9          09.01.2023         0
Customer B       10         10.01.2023         0
Customer B       11         11.01.2023         0
Customer D       12         12.01.2023         0
Customer C       13         13.01.2023         0
Customer D       14         14.01.2023         0
Customer C       15         15.01.2023         0
```

and here is bascially how my power BI page looks like as an example, the aboe slicer should control what is being shown in matrix below it

[image]

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected result. Do you have a .pbix you can share?

Comment: I could add a sample .pbix but don't see an option to attach a file here...

Comment: That's fine. Can you update your question with your sample date in copiable tabular format. Is this a calculated column you require or a measure? Where is the context for 09.01.2023 coming from as the visual doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added example data along with the picture of example power BI page. I would like to have this as a measrue since then I have though to place this measure as a filter for my visualization so only values with 1 would be shown in visualisation

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So let's take 09.01.2023 as a reference. I would like to add value = 1 to csutomers A and E because they did buy sth before 09.01.2023 but did not buy anything after 09.01.2023 and would like to add value = 0 to the rest customers since they did buy sth after 09.01.2023